# How to copy from current clipboard selection to terminal with a command and without mouse

Tags: command-line, scripts, clipboard

Thank you for your support.
I wish to make a bash script that uses the latest text copied and currently in clipboard.

Answer (score 4):

There are keyboard shortcuts for GUI terminals , Ctrl+Shift+V and Shift+Insert already. A script and mouse are unnecessary here.

If you're specifically looking for commands, there are `xclip` and `xsel`. Both of them are used to manipulate clipboards ( of which there are two in Linux - primary and secondary, that's why two different keyboard shortcuts were mentioned in the beginning of this answer ). I am personally more of a `xclip` fan, and i regularly use `echo text | xclip -sel clip` to copy something to clipboard and `xclip -out -sel clip` to print out whatever is in my clipboard. This is especially useful when you want to filter out text or process text with another command like `xclip -out -sel clip | grep 'some text that I am looking for'`

NOTE: `xclip` and `xsel` don't come to Ubuntu by default. You must install them with `sudo apt-get install PACKAGE_NAME` command

If we want to go into TTY, there's no way to copy text there. You must either use something known as `named pipe` or just a plain text file.

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage `xdotool` for simulating the keyboard and mouse.

So for pasting a text from clipboard we use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, you can simulate this in `xdotool` by:

```
xdotool key ctrl+shift+v
```

Also check of mouse actions, read `man xdotool`.

---

If not installed, install it by (available in the Universe repository):

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Comment: `code`(#! /bin/bash
kdeconnect-send $(zenity --text="escriba la url a compartir" --entry --entry-text=$(xclip -o)))

Comment: I have used with good results: :`code`(#! /bin/bash
kdeconnect-send $(zenity --text="escriba la url a compartir" --entry --entry-text=$(xclip -o))) a mini script for sharing url to kdeconnect. However the xdotool solution that you offered seems to work too. I really appreciate your help, but now i'd like to ask if you know some way  to automatically copy chromium's current tab url. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution while i was surfing trhough this forum. 
i had to install "xclip"

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

then i use it in the terminal:

```
"$(xclip -o)"
```